# Class 'MongoDB\Driver\Manager' not found

Tags: mongodb, laravel, laravel-5

I'm integrating MongoDB with Laravel. I'm following information found in this link [jenssegers/laravel-mongodb](https://github.com/jenssegers/laravel-mongodb#installation). I'm successful at integrating MongoDB. But when I run the code it throws this error

> FatalErrorException in Client.php line 56:
>   Class 'MongoDB\Driver\Manager' not found

Here is the code

**Controller**
   app/Http/Controller/NewController

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Http\Requests;

use App\User;

class NewController extends Controller
{
    //
    public function index(){
        $var = User::all();
        var_dump($var);
    }
}
```

And here follows the `user.php` that is by default provided by Laravel when we create the project

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Jenssegers\Mongodb\Eloquent\Model as Eloquent;

class User  extends Eloquent 
{
    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $collection = 'users_collection';
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'password',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes excluded from the model's JSON form.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];
}
```

Please tell me why am I getting this error.

Phpinfo --> mongodb section is coming. Here is a screen shot
[phpinfo](http://screencast.com/t/NjWZ735d)

Comment: This indicates that the MongoDB extension hasn't been loaded. Did you check the output of `phpinfo()` or `php -i | grep mongo`? Did you restart the web server after install?

Comment: @Fiskie yes and there I can see the mongo section

Comment: @Fiskie I have added the screenshot

Comment: @Fiskie I ran the command that you told and it 's output is `output is not a tty
`

Comment: @Fiskie See my answer below. This error is thrown during a few scenarios. Might help debugging other people's issues.

Answer (score 13):

I do not know if it's the most elegant solution, but it worked for me:

1. Install the php driver `$ sudo pecl install mongodb`
2. Create the extension file `$ sudo nano /etc/php5/mods-available/mongodb.ini` and write inside: **extension=mongodb.so**
3. Create a symbolic link for this file `$ sudo ln -sv /etc/php5/mods-available/mongodb.ini  /etc/php5/apache2/conf.d/20-mongodb.ini`
4. Create an other symbolic link for this file `$ sudo ln -sv /etc/php5/mods-available/mongodb.ini  /etc/php5/cli/conf.d/20-mongodb.ini`
5. Restart apache or the server used `$ sudo service apache2 restart`

It may be necessary to reinstall jenssegers/mongodb: `$ composer require jenssegers/mongodb`

Comment: My working platform is windows. Can you tell how can I do this in windows.

Comment: In this [link](https://pecl.php.net/package/mongodb/1.1.3/windows) you can find the mongodb driver (php_mongodb.dll) for PHP on Windows systems. Download the correct version for PHP and the system (x86 or x64) driver. Copy this DLL in the extension folder, in my case `C:\wamp64\bin\php\php5.6.16\ext` and add this line in php.ini: `extension=php_mongodb.dll`. Restart the Apache server and try again. Note that you must edit the php.ini file in this path (`C:\wamp64\bin\php\php5.6.16`, if used Wamp) and not Wamp icon on the taskbar.

Comment: I was getting this error after doing all the steps you told (I'm talking about the steps which you told in the section )

Comment: Do you have any error during these steps? Note that you may have some errors on the dependencies while trying to install the mongodb driver.

Comment: I think I missed a detail. It is also necessary to add the line extension=php_mongodb.dll in the apache php.ini file, that is, which is on the route \bin\apache\apache2.4.17\bin\php.ini.

Comment: sorry for the late reply I'm still not able to attach the mongodb with my application. I did  not get any error during the installation and I have added that extension but still not success

Comment: Note that you need to add the line `extension=php_mongodb.dll` in both php.ini files(`\bin\php\php5.6.16\php.ini` and `\bin\apache\apache2.4.17\bin\php.ini`)

Comment: How can i make this work for Mac? Having the same issue.

Answer (score 11):

You may also need to restart fpm on ubuntu/debian

```
sudo service php7.0-fpm restart
```

for php5

```
sudo service php5-fpm restart
```

Also, make sure `extension=mongodb.so` is in:

```
apache2/php.ini
cli/php.ini
fpm/php.ini
```

to check i do:

```
locate php.ini | xargs grep mongo
```

to see php.ini files:

```
php --ini
```

Comment: Was only doing nginx restart, had to restart php too. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

When you are going to connect MongoDB database with any PHP application then you can face this issue if you don't have PHP MongoDB driver.

So first you need to run following command to install Mongodb PHP extension :

```
sudo apt-get install php-mongodb
```

Now restart the server :

```
  sudo service apache2 restart
```

[reference from hdtuto](https://hdtuto.com/article/php-laravel-56-class-mongodbdrivermanager-not-found)

Comment: May not solve the original question, but this definitely helped me. I had mongodb installed, but apparently installing php-mongodb did the trick. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

As of 2017 this should work for PHP 5.6:

```
### Install MongoDB driver for PHP 5.6 ##############

echo -e "\n### Installing MongoDB PHP driver ##\n";
sudo apt-get install php-mongodb -y

# Make sure extension=mongodb.so is present

PhpConfigFile="/etc/php/5.6/fpm/php.ini"
if grep -q mongodb.so "$PhpConfigFile"; then
  echo "extension=mongodb.so already found, dont add."
else
  echo "extension=mongodb.so" | sudo tee "$PhpConfigFile"
  echo "Added extension=mongodb.so to $PhpConfigFile"
fi
```

---

It is part of my one-liner installer of PHP5.6 + nginx + MongoDB plugin for PHP, I've even made a domain for it:
http://ubuntu-script.tk

Answer (score 2):

The answer can be found here:
[Why MongoDB Class doesn't work in Laravel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38790411/why-mongodb-class-doesnt-work-in-laravel)

[apokryfos](https://stackoverflow.com/users/487813/apokryfos) gives us the answer in the first comment:

> Try new \MongoClient() instead

For anyone struggling to get the **mongodb.so** extension working for PHP, be careful, there are two mongo drivers for PHP. For the new driver follow these instructions:
http://php.net/manual/en/mongodb.installation.manual.php

Make sure all your php.ini files contain:

```
extension=mongodb.so
```

From the root of your project:

```
composer require mongodb/mongodb
```

In your PHP file:

**NOTE THE BACKSLASH BEFORE MongoDB**

```
$client = new \MongoDB\Client("mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017");
$collection = $client->database->collection;

$cursor = $collection->find(
    [
        'some.nice.name' => 'true'
    ]
);
```

Comment: I have lampp(XAMPP) installed my system, I'm trying to add php extension "mongodb.so". Also I built it successfully following instructions of (https://secure.php.net/manual/en/mongodb.installation.manual.php) even after adding it my phpinfo() doesn't shows any mongo related thing(field) and I'm still getting the same error, so what should i do??

Comment: The critical line is $client = new \MongoDB\Client("mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017"); but this is for Linux. You'll have to search for how that line should look in Windows. If the syntax is the same for Windows then PHP is not finding the MongoDB Client.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it could help you.

If you are using the new Wamp server, make sure that the php interpreter that your ide is using if the same use by wamp and where you have install the mongodb.dll.

I was having the same issue.

I resolved it when i installed mongodb.dll both on php 5.6.25 and 7.0.10, because my wamp server have the two versions.
After the installation, i made a composer update. 
Now it is ok.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume that you have php-mongodb installed correctly no matter what the process.

I hit this error when the mongo connection string was empty:

```
new MongoDB\Client('mongodb://');
```

Make sure your mongo connection string is populated properly.

Answer (score 0):

WINDOWS USERS:
In the folder

```
C:\xampp\php\ext
```

Copy the php_mongodb.dll file. You can get this file from the link according to your php version, ts or non ts and architecture from this link:
https://pecl.php.net/package/mongodb/1.9.0/windows

In windows , if anybody couldn't locate the php.ini file, its in the folder

```
C:\xampp\php
```

inside this the php file with the type configuration settings.

I couldnt locate this, as the extension .ini was not showing in mine.