# Laravel 5.2 and jenssegers/mongodb REST API with virtualhost

Tags: php, mongodb, laravel, laravel-5, jenssegers-mongodb

I am creating a REST API with Laravel 5.2 and I'm also using MongoDB with the jenssegers/mongodb library. I have a virtualhost for my application so I can go to the url eg: `http://myapp.local.com` and simulate how it would be on the real server and as I have some other Laravel projects on dev right now, it is more organised to have them this way.

The virtualhost is pointing to the `public` folder of my application and it's working correctly.

This project is just starting so everything is being built right now. In order to check the database I created a very simple `PostsController` just to see if the connection and the results were returned correctly. I added `Route::resource('/posts', 'PostsController');` in my **routes.php** so I could start doing some tests of basic CRUD operations.

When I use `php artisan serve` and access this route with `http://localhost:8000/posts` the results are brought correctly but when I try to access via `http://myapp.local.com/posts` I get this error:

```
FatalErrorException in Client.php line 56:
Class 'MongoDB\Driver\Manager' not found
```

Any ideas why this is happening?

Comment: Also having the same issue. Are you running on Mac, Windows or Linux? @shattered_skies29 have you tried this fix? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35920568/class-mongodb-driver-manager-not-found

Comment: I am running this on Mac. I also saw that post and tried something similar but not exactly that. Have you tried it? Have you had any luck with this issue?

Comment: I'm running on Mac & haven't managed to get it working. Running on PHP7 and have extension-mongodb.so in php.ini. No luck.

Comment: And are you having the exact same issue? If you serve your app with artisan does it work correctly? Because that's the weird thing :/

Comment: Running the app off localhost and that's the identical error i'm getting even on the same line number.

Comment: any luck with this issue @imbayago?

Comment: Haven't managed to get it working on localhost, but managed to get it working on a Digital Ocean cloud server.