# Why MongoDB Class doesn't work in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, mongodb, laravel-5

I want to use MongoDB in Laravel. This is my code inside of the controller:

```
public function create (Request $request) {
    $m = new MongoClient();
    $db = $m->selectDB("Laravel");      
    $collection = $db->selectCollection("Posts");
    $document = array( 
       "Title" => $request->input('Title'), 
       "Publisher" => $request->input('Publisher')
    );      
    $collection->insert($document);
}
```

But when I click "Submit", it gives me an error :

> Fatal error: Class 'App\Http\Controllers\MongoClient' not found

I have run MongoDB Server and also Wamp and I have installed MongoDB and it's driver for PHP …

What is my mistake ?
(I should say that I haven't done any config for Laravel by using MongoDB. Is it needed ?)

Comment: Try `new \MongoClient()` instead

Comment: @apokryfos Thanks but It showed this : Fatal error: Class 'MongoClient' not found

Comment: Did you install [the MogoClient](http://php.net/manual/en/class.mongoclient.php) or [the MongoDB client](http://php.net/manual/en/set.mongodb.php)?

Comment: @apokryfos I have installed MongoDB 3.2 & It's driver but I haven't installed the MongoClient ..., Indeed I haven't done any CONFIG for laravel, Is it needed ?

Comment: You said you installed its driver for PHP, I've given you links to 2 different clients for PHP, you need to check which one you've installed because they use different class names. Unless you've installed another one.

Comment: @apokryfos Sorry My Friend, I'm getting confused. I have just downloaded MongoDB (v 3.2) & Its driver for PHP 7. What is MongoClient?
I haven't installed that ...

Comment: What is this *mongoDB driver for PHP* you keep mentioning? Any link to it?

Comment: @apokryfos I have read for using PHP & MongoDB we should use a driver for PHP, I installed MongoDB v3.2 from its site & its driver for PHP from this link : https://docs.mongodb.com/ecosystem/drivers/php/

Comment: You should really read the [documentation](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-php-library/?jmp=docs&_ga=1.237419200.137669209.1470406381) of what you've downloaded. Namely the client class name is `\MongoDB\Client`

Comment: @apokryfos Sorry but I didn't get what you said ...

Comment: In short I said read the documentation at http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-php-library/?jmp=docs&_ga=1.237419200.137669209.1470406381

Comment: @apokryfos Thanks ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Laravel doesn't come with a driver for MongoDB.

If you want to use mongo with laravel you'll have to create your own class to deal with it or use this one:

[laravel-mongodb](https://github.com/jenssegers/laravel-mongodb)

Comment: Thanks My Friend but I don't want to use package, I'm beginner I prefer to use it regularly ...

Comment: I'm not following your logic. If you're a beginner, wouldn't it follow that you would want to use a pre-built package specific to the framework you're using instead of rolling your own implementation?

Comment: Rolling my own implementation is better than a package, Especially for me that I want to understand more the MongoDB Syntax ...