# "Class 'MongoDB\Driver\Manager' not found" in PHP

Tags: php, mongodb, composer-php

I installed MongoDB library with Composer:

```
composer require jenssegers/mongodb
```

I got that error: "Class 'MongoDB\Driver\Manager' not found",

I tried many things but problem is not solved,
But finally I noticed that the class file is really not existing in library!
I havent found it anyway...

What am I missing?

Where can I found full package for MongoDB in PHP?

**Please be aware of that: similar questions are not mentioning lack of class file.**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Class 'MongoDB\Driver\Manager' not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35920568/class-mongodb-driver-manager-not-found)

Comment: No, they are talking about "extension" and "backslashes", but lack of class file...

Comment: This class comes from PHP extension, so lack of class file is a direct result of missing extension. So this *is* a duplicate - just install `mongodb` extension.

Answer (score 1):

Usually your code should contain a link to **'vendor/autoload.php'** with the correct path to it similar to the following:

```
  $DB_CONNECTION_STRING="mongodb://YourCredentials";
  require '../../vendor/autoload.php';
```

Then if you use MongoDB\Driver\Manager, a modern version of MongoDB driver, you have something such as these CRUD operations in your code:

***Create** a document in the collection*:

```
$bulkWrite = new MongoDB\Driver\BulkWrite;
$doc=['name' => 'John', age => 33, profession => 'Guess what?'];
$bulk->insert($doc);
$mongoConn->executeBulkWrite('db.col', $bulkWrite);
```

***Read** document in the collection* by name with a limit:

```
$filter = ['name' => 'John'];
$options = ['limit' => 2];
$query = new MongoDB\Driver\Query($filter, $options);
$mongoConn->executeQuery('db.MyCollection', $query);
```

***Read** document in the collection* by MongoDb _id with a limit:

```
$filter = ['_id' => new MongoDB\BSON\ObjectID( '5bdf54e6d722dc000f0aa6c2' )];
$options = ['limit' => 2];
$query = new MongoDB\Driver\Query($filter, $options);
$mongoConn->executeQuery('db.MyCollection', $query);
```

***Update** document in the collection*:

```
$bulkWrite = new MongoDB\Driver\BulkWrite;
$filter = [];
$update = ['$set' => array()];
$options = ['multi' => false, 'upsert' => false];
$bulkWrite->update($filter, $update, $options);
$mongoConn->executeBulkWrite('db.MyCollection', $bulkWrite);
```

***Delete** document in the collection - Delete*:

```
$bulkWrite = new MongoDB\Driver\BulkWrite;
$filter = ['name' => 'John', age => 33];
$options = ['limit' => 1];
$bulkWrite->delete($filter, $options);
$mongoConn->executeBulkWrite('db.col', $bulkWrite);
```